# How to filter nested array after $group stage in aggregation pipeline in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I asked a question regarding grouping $lookup results within inner arrays a while ago, link to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300441/group-lookup-results-within-inner-nested-array-and-keep-outer-nested-array-and)

I have a dataset that looks like this with lookup results

```
_id: ObjectID('abc'),
sections: [
   {
   sectionId: "sec0",
   sectionName: "ABC",
   contents: [
      {
      contentId: 0,
      tasks: [
         {
          _id: task01
          //properties of task01
          duration: '2 days',
         },
         {
          _id: task02
          //properties of task02
          duration: '3 days',
         },
    ],
    contentDescription: "Content is etc",
    }
  ]
}
{
   sectionId: "sec1",
   sectionName: "EFG",
   contents: [
      {
      contentId: 0,
      tasks: [
         {
          _id: task03
          //properties of task03
          duration: '4 days',
         },
         {
          _id: task04
          //properties of task04
          duration: '3 days',
         },
    ],
    contentDescription: "Content is etc",
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I used the following aggregation pipeline

```
{
      $match: {
        _id: id,
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$sections',
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$sections.contents',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$sections.contents.tasks',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tasks',
        let: {
          task_id: '$sections.contents.tasks.tId',
          duration: '$sections.contents.tasks.duration',
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $eq: ['$_id', '$$task_id'],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $addFields: {
              duration: '$$duration',
            },
          },
        ],
        as: 'sections.contents.tasks',
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        'sections.contents.tasks': {
          $arrayElemAt: ['$sections.contents.tasks', 0],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          contentId: '$sections.contents.tasks',
          sectionId: '$sections.sectionId',
          sectionName: '$sections.sectionName',
          originalId: '$_id',
        },
        tasks: {
          $push: '$sections.contents.tasks',
        },
        contentDescription: {
          $first: '$sections.contents.contentDescription',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { _id: 1 },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          sectionId: '$_id.sectionId',
          sectionName: '$_id.sectionName',
          originalId: '$_id.originalId',
        },
        contents: {
          $push: {
            contentId: '$_id.contentId',
            tasks: '$tasks',
            contentDescription: '$contentDescription',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id.originalId',
        sections: {
          $push: {
            sectionId: '$_id.sectionId',
            sectionName: '$_id.sectionName',
            contents: '$contents',
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

And everything works perfectly, but there is a wrinkle, suppose if a person adds a section without adding its contents, then the following data is saved in MongoDB

```
 [
       {
       sectionId: "sec0",
       sectionName: "ABC",
       contents: [
          {
          contentId: 0,
          tasks: [
             {
              _id: task01
              //properties of task01
              duration: '2 days',
             },
             {
              _id: task02
              //properties of task02
              duration: '3 days',
             },
        ],
        contentDescription: "Content is etc",
        }
      ]
    }
    {
       sectionId: "sec1",
       sectionName: "EFG",    
    }
    ]
```

And for every get request, I am getting the following results (only posting second section element)

```
{
   sectionId: "sec1",
   sectionName: "EFG",
   contents: [
      {
       tasks: [],
       contentDescription: null,
       }
     ]
}
```

And due to this, client-side is lighting up as it cant find both *contentDescription*, and *tasks* and all the checks fail due to the presence of contents array. Refactoring is not possible for both client-side and backend schemas.

The **desired** output is as follows in case if no contents array is present

```
_id: ObjectID('abc'),
sections: [
   {
   sectionId: "sec0",
   sectionName: "ABC",
   contents: [
      {
      contentId: 0,
      tasks: [
         {
          _id: task01
          //properties of task01
          duration: '2 days',
         },
         {
          _id: task02
          //properties of task02
          duration: '3 days',
         },
    ],
    contentDescription: "Content is etc",
    }
  ]
}
{
   sectionId: "sec1",
   sectionName: "EFG",
}
]
```

I added the following stage after last group stage in aggregation pipeline as follows

```
{
   $addFields: {
      'sections.contents.tasks': {
        $filter: {
           input: '$sections.contents.tasks',
           as: 'task',
           cond: {
                   $ne: ['$$task', []],
                 },
           },
       },
    },
   },
```

But its not working, any suggestions or help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this be avoided by using `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false` when unwinding the tasks array?

Comment: That was the first thing I did, but unfortunately it dosen't work as $unwind does not output the tasks array, and as a result I get an empty array. I am sure there is some way using $cond or any other relevant aggregation query in $project stage after last $group stage that ensures that if contentDescription is null, and tasks is empty, then filter out contents array. I tried using $project but I am stumped at $cond

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://mongoplayground.net/p/fQL6Fw8pArk

Comment: **preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false** doesn't works if no tasks array is present, which is the crux of my problem

Comment: @Joe and besides, the aggregation pipeline does not display section without any contents array in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data set to make sure that content is added compulsory then just add a condition

```
if(!req.body.contents){
     return {
        status: 400,
        message: Contents not specified;
}
```

Comment: The problem does not arise from client-side, otherwise second section would have been stored in MongoDB with empty contents. The problem is that I am using lookup in aggregation pipeline, and the group stages adds both tasks array, and contentDescription whether its present in the input document sections array or not